# Meaning of exclamation mark in iOS Designer on Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm working with the iOS Designer and I have a storyboard with different views on it (navigation controller, ...). On nearly each view there is a red exclamation mark on the right side at the bottom. I get errors like

> System.NullReferenceException
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object

If I go to the corresponding code line:

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
{
    return TopViewController.GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations();
}
```

This is part of my `CustomNavigationController`. If I set the class name on the iOS Designer I get the error. What do I have to add here? The constructor looks like the following:

```
public CustomNavigationController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
}
```

Do I have to instantiate it in the AppDelegate?

On another view controller I get a similar Exception (with a different stack) and it points me to this line:

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB (21, 66, 139);
```

The app seems to work fine on simulator and on device though.

How do I resolve this issue?

**EDIT:**

I now removed the code in my view controller:

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB (21, 66, 139);
```

As replacement I moved this code to the Application Delegate `FinishedLaunching()`:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB (21, 66, 139);
```

The result is that now I don't have the exclamation mark for this view controller and the color is as desired. But the preview in the iOS Designer doesn't show me the correct color anymore.

If I comment out `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()` in my `CustomNavigationController` than the other exclamation mark has been removed. I thought I need this function for defining the orientation of each view controller. A quick look showed that it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are restriction on what the design time can support. You should replace any dynamic data, for example data loaded from a service, with dummy data when on design mode. The same applies to runtime objects like `TopViewController` which is only available at runtime.

```
if (Site != null && Site.DesignMode)
{
    // use dummy data for designer surface
}
else
{
    // use live data
}
```

This document explains it in more detail:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_overview/

Comment: Thanks for the info I didn't know that. So I should add a default orientation when in design mode? Is this also valid for accessing `this.NavigationController`? I don't know why I can't access the navigation controller. In the iOS Designer the navigation bar is missing on this view.

Comment: Now I tried to use this approach but I still get `System.NullReferenceException` in iOS Designer ... Here is the code `if (Site != null && Site.DesignMode) {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
} else {
return TopViewController.GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ();
}`

Comment: I again tried it with a string. I get `UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency`. This approach doesn't work.